# Mapping values between two Objects and reading the values

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

**UPDATED:**

I think I made it easier for comparison and now I'm left with a case where I have an object:

**Object A**

```
['B', 'A']
```

**Object B**

```
[{ AccountNumber: 'A',
    'ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda': 'UPDATE_COMPLETE',
  },
  { AccountNumber: 'C',
    'ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda': 'UPDATE_COMPLETE',
  }]
```

I want to see if either of the two Account numbers from Object A are inside Object B

In this example; Account A would pass the *ifelse* since it is in Object B however Account C would not pass since it Object A does not contain it.

Comment: You call `forEach` on AccountInfoReturn which you are saying is like Object B, but Object B is an object not an array and so there is no `forEach`. Is AccountInfo Return actually an array of objects _like_ B or did you mean to go over something else?

Comment: Please be clear what is your desired result

Comment: Also why does Account 1, 2, and 3 fall under the case where it's "Decommissioned or waiting" when Account 1 is `Decommissioned: false, Waiting: false,` in `accountStatusList`

Comment: @decpk I updated the prompt to make it easier to digest. Essentially I just want to do a comparison between Object A and B even if it's out of order to see if there are any matching values between the two.

Comment: I'd like to note that this example is extremely different than your initial one. Determining if a value from A is in B is a very different process than finding nested keys in objects and fetching particular information and using values in a structure. You mention an if-else that has been removed so for future viewers of this question it will no longer make sense. Can you please update your question to include all of the information necessary to both understand and create a viable solution for a reasonable representation of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to go through `A` and check existence with [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in B.

```js
const A = ["B", "A"];
const B = [
  { AccountNumber: "A", "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE" },
  { AccountNumber: "C", "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE" },
];

A.forEach((acc) => {
  if (B.find((o) => o.AccountNumber === acc)) {
    console.log("Pass the test");
  } else {
    console.log("Doesn't Pass the test");
  }
});
```

If you want to grab the object that pass the test

```js
const A = ["B", "A"];
const B = [{
    AccountNumber: "A",
    "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE"
  },
  {
    AccountNumber: "C",
    "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE"
  },
];

const result = [];
A.forEach((acc) => {
  const objInExistence = B.find((o) => o.AccountNumber === acc);
  if (objInExistence) {
    console.log("Pass the test");
    result.push(objInExistence);
  } else {
    console.log("Doesn't Pass the test");
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

**EDITED CODE**

```js
const A = ["B", "A"];
const B = [
  { AccountNumber: "A", "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE" },
  { AccountNumber: "C", "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE" },
  { AccountNumber: "C", "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE" },
  { AccountNumber: "C", "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE" },
  { AccountNumber: "C", "ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda": "UPDATE_COMPLETE" },
];

B.forEach((acc) => {
  if (A.find((o) => o === acc.AccountNumber)) {
    console.log("Pass the test");
  } else {
    console.log("Doesn't Pass the test");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Sam I tried the following and it worked however I was looking to compare the two objects the other way around. If B is in A.
For example:
running the following code snippet works and produces two logs since there are only 2 values in A. However I want the code to run for however many values there are inside 'B'. So if B has 5 Account Numbers then it should run five times checking against the 2 values in A

Comment: @krispikimchi updated code. Please check. Is this what you want. There are 3 code snippet in my answer. So check the last one

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrayA = [{ Decommissioned: false,
    Waiting: false,
    Account: '1' },
    { Decommissioned: false,
        Waiting: true,
        Account: '2' },
    { Decommissioned: true,
        Waiting: false,
        Account: '3' },
    { Decommissioned: false,
        Waiting: false,
        Account: '4' }]


// Case if B is an array
var arrayB = [{
    "Account": "1",
    "AccountType": "DEV",
    "ProductionAccount": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
}]

const shouldProceed = arrayB.filter((b) => {
    const find = arrayA.find((a) => (a.Account === b.Account));
    return (find && (find.Waiting || find.Decommissioned));
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes),
or even Array.prototype.some or Array.prototype.every (if you need booleans).

Here's an example with two reusable functions:

```js
const findOne = (arr, prop, val) => arr.find(x => x[prop] === val);
const findMany = (arr, prop, arrVal) => arr.filter(x => arrVal.includes(x[prop]));

const accounts = [
  {AccountNumber: 'A', 'ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda': 'UPDATE_COMPLETE'},
  {AccountNumber: 'C','ProdAccount-Nested-Lambda': 'UPDATE_COMPLETE'},
];

console.log(findOne(accounts, "AccountNumber", "C"));              // [{C}]
console.log(findOne(accounts, "AccountNumber", "B"));              // undefined
console.log(findMany(accounts, "AccountNumber", ["B", "A"]));      // [{A}]
console.log(findMany(accounts, "AccountNumber", ["C", "B", "A"])); // [{A}, {C}]
```